# mySQL ORDER BY using FOREIGN KEYS

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

I essentially want to sort a specific query result by a Foreign Key's entry's column. Here are the tables I have:

```
class
------
classId
profId    //Points to a profId from professor table
courseId  //Points to a specific courseId from course table
semId     //Points to a specific semId from semester table

professor
---------
profId
first   //first name
last    //last name

course
------
courseId
department //The `CMSC` in CMSC101
number    //The `101` in CMSC101
title    

semester
--------
semId
season  //example: Spring, Summer, Fall
year
```

I want them to be ordered hierarchally, but also by the foreign keys in the class column's columns. So, I would `SELECT` all the entries from `class` and sort them in this order:

1. course -> department
2. course -> number
3. course -> section
4. professor -> last
5. professor -> first
6. semester -> year
7. semester -> season

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah, that makes more sense than the prior posting of the question. You first need to join all the tables together, then you can sort:

```
SELECT
  Course.Department,
  Course.Number,
  Course.Section,
  Professor.Last,
  Professor.First,
  Semester.Year,
  Semester.Season
FROM Class
INNER JOIN Course ON Class.CourseID = Course.CourseID
INNER JOIN Professor ON Class.ProfID = Professor.ProfID
INNER JOIN Semester ON Class.SemID = Semester.SemID
ORDER BY
  Course.Department,
  Course.Number,
  Course.Section,
  Professor.Last,
  Professor.First,
  Semester.Year,
  Semester.Season
```

The columns don't *have* to be in the `SELECT` list for you to sort by them, but in most cases it makes sense to include them there.

Comment: This is a fairly straightforward `SELECT` so the first place to start is with the documentation [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html). If there's a specific part of the query above that you're having a hard time understanding just let me know and I'll try to explain.

Comment: Is it possible to add a `WHERE professor.last='Smith'` and narrow that query down to only show the classes that have a professor with the last name "Smith"?

Comment: Absolutely. Your syntax is correct; just put it after the `INNER JOIN` and before the `ORDER BY`.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming a join on all tables, why not just

ORDER BY COL1, COL2, ...COLN

When you perform a join, you will have access to all of the columns in each of the join tables. Example:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/30e14/1